# Assets disappear when running webpack --watch if files other than the template are modified

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I've created small project which consists of one HTML file and a few assets (images, video, (S)CSS, JS) and I use webpack (latest versions of all installed packages) to optimize and bundle the files. Processing the SCSS and JS files works fine so far, but bundling the images and videos, which are included in the HTML template, does not work as desired.

**Problem**: When I execute `webpack --watch`, the images/videos are copied correctly to the dist folder, but only on the first run. If I modify e.g. a SCSS or JS file, the images and videos disappear from the dist folder whereas JS and CSS files are properly generated/updated. If I then edit the HTML template, the images/videos reappear in the dist folder.

The most relevant parts of my code (see below for a link to see/download the project for easier reproduction of the problem):

```js
// webpack.config.js

// ...
const config = {
  src: 'src/',
  dist: 'dist/',
  jsEntry: '/assets/js/main.js',
  cssEntry: '/assets/scss/main.scss',
  publicPath: '/',
};

const absEntryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, config.src);
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    style: absEntryPath + config.cssEntry,
    main: absEntryPath + config.jsEntry
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.dist),
    publicPath: config.publicPath,
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:4].min.js',
    clean: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: config.src + 'index.ejs',
      cache: false,
      // ...
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/css/[name].[contenthash:4].min.css'
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        // html
        test: /\.(html|ejs)$/,
        exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              sources: true,
              minimize: false,
              esModule: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        // styles
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        use: [
           // ...
        ]
      },
      {
        // images
        test: /\.(jp(e)?g|png|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: '[name].[contenthash:4].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/img/',
            publicPath: config.publicPath
          }
        }
      },
      {
        // video
        test: /\.(mp4|mov)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: '[name].[contenthash:4].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/video/',
            publicPath: config.publicPath
          }
        }
      },
      // ...
    ]
  },
  // ...
};
```

```html
<!-- /src/index.ejs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <!-- ... -->
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>some image</p>
      <img src="./assets/img/some-image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>some video</p>
      <video controls poster="./assets/video/some-video_poster.png">
        <source src="./assets/video/some-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Similar behavior has already been described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10761) and [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1432) with the recommendation to disable caching for `html-webpack-plugin`, but as you can see in my webpack.config.js I'm already using `cache: false` and it doesn't fix the problem.

As a workaround, I'm currently excluding the images/videos from the dist folder cleanup, however this forces me to keep the filenames which I don't really want to due to possible browser caching issues.

**Question**: How can I prevent the images/videos from disappearing from the dist folder when I edit files other than the HTML template? I would prefer to be able to use hashes in the filenames and not have to exclude the files from the dist folder cleanup.

---

*I've uploaded a stripped down version of the project to Stackblitz, where you can [download](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-assets-disappear?file=webpack.config.js) it. Please note that I do not have a pro account and therefore could not upload pictures/videos. If you want to reproduce the problem, please replace the two images and the video locally.*

Answer (score 0):

did you ever solve this? I've got a similar issue - images always appear on first load, then disappear when changing any js or ts file.

changes to the html also do the same, but about 1 in 3 reloads/saves make the images reappear (this doesn't happen with the js files)

---

****Edit with answer:** I mistakenly added this as an answer, but have stumbled across one for my problem

Removing `clean: true` fixed it for me. The cache option didn't have an impact unfortunately

Comment: No, unfortunately not. As I wrote in my question, excluding problematic file types or deactivating the cleanup is a way around the problem, but only as long as you keep the file names the same (e.g. no hashes/random names). Otherwise it leads to many outdated files in the output folder. It is of course possible to delete the output folder manually every now and then to remove these obsolete files (that's what I do at the moment), but it would be nice if this extra step could be avoided.